# MySql use default value if searched doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I'm working with MySQL

I have a Actions_table which has an action an number of users.
I also have a Timing_table which I map the timing of each action to do.

I can match up the action in the Actions table to the Timing table but I want it to use a default time if there is no exact match eg tables

```
Actions_Table
------------------------------
| Action       | No Ids      |
------------------------------
|Delete ID    | 5            |
|Install App1 | 1            |
|Create ID    | 1            |
|Rename ID    | 2            |
------------------------------

Timing_Table
-------------------
|Action      |Time |     
-------------------
|Delete ID   | 100 |
|Install App1| 200 |
|Create ID   | 50  |
|Default     | 60  |
--------------------
```

As there is nothing listed for "Rename ID" in the Timings_Table I want it to use the time value for 'Default' instead so I will have something link this.

```
-------------------------------------
| Action       | No Ids | Total Time|
-------------------------------------
|Delete ID    | 5       |  500      |
|Install App1 | 1       |  200      |
|Create ID    | 1       |  50       |
|Rename ID    | 2       |  120      |  <== value was calculated from Default
-------------------------------------
```

The basic code

```
Select a.Action, a.`No Ids`, (a.`No Ids` * b.time) as `TotalTime
From Action_Table a, Timing_Table b
Where a.Action = b.Action
```

However that won't match any unmatched to Default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a `left join` and a `cross join`:

```
Select a.Action, a.`No Ids`,
       coalesce(b.time, def.time) as ImputedBTime,
       (a.`No Ids` * coalesce(b.time, def.time)) as `TotalTime
From Action_Table a left join
     Timing_Table b
     on a.Action = b.Action cross join
     (select t.* from Timing_Table t where t.action = 'default') def
```

Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  You should learn the different types of joins.